# How to move my menu in the right side

Tags: javascript, css

I was designing this webpage for one of my client. I'm using bootstrap & flexnav for my navigation Menu. I want to align my whole navigation area right side of the page, but it is floating in the left now. I have tried to add float:right to ul class, but it is not working. how can I fix it?
http://banglapdf.net/Testing/theme/

Comment: What is floating left? Don't see anything like that..

Comment: Realy, what must be floating?

Comment: I want to float the area in right side, not left.

Comment: sorry it is float left

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The width of your `ul` is preventing it from moving any further to the right.
You can either make it less wide (making it auto should work), and float it right, or you can float right the `li`s inside it.

Comment: Good to hear. If you set the width of the ul to auto, that should work for you.